# Ordered Basis for $M_{2\times2}(\mathbb R)$ such that $T(A) = A^T$ is a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> I'd like to get an ordered basis $\beta$ for $M_{2\times2}(\mathbb R)$ such that $[T]_\beta$ is a diagonal matrix where $T(A) = A^T$.

First I have took the ordered basis $\beta = {\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}}$

and from the equation $[T]_{\beta_0}v = \lambda v$,

$[T]_{\beta_0}v - \lambda v = 0$ , which is same to $([T]_{\beta_0} - \lambda I)v  = 0$

$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix} -\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$

for $v_0 = \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$,

$\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}v_0 = \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\-c&-d\end{pmatrix}=0$, thus $c,d =0$ for $v_0$ . Therefore,

$v_0 = \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Is it correct?

Comment: You want eigenvectors.  Your second and third vectors aren't.  But their sum and difference are.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find eigenvectors of the $T$ operation, that is matrices $A$
with $T(A)=\lambda A$. In that case $T^2(A)=\lambda^2A$ but $T^2(A)=A$
so $\lambda^2=1$. For each solution of $\lambda^2=1$ you need to find a basis for the set of matrices satisfying $T(A)=A^T=\lambda A$.